# How do you change URL path with a button when using Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, meteor, hyperlink

I understand when you would want to load another html file by clicking on a certain element in just plain html you would use something like this:

```
<a href="index2.html">Example Link</a>
```

but how should I go about doing this in a Meteor application. The situation for me is I want to click a submit button and have the button not only submit a certain form I have, but change the path to another page. Right now in my meteor app I am using kadira flow router and have some directories set up, so I figured I would just make an onclick function that renders that flow router. Here is the code I tried for that:

route code:

```
FlowRouter.route('/joinLobby', {
  name: 'joinLobby',
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('joinLobby');
  }
});
```

onclick function:

```
<script>
  function renderPage(){
    BlazeLayout.render('joinLobby');
  }
</script>
```

button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"    onclick="renderPage()">Insert</button>
```

I'm not really sure if this is the best practice, this is just what I threw together to get to another page, so I'm asking whats the best way to do this.  Also this gives me some problems when I use it.  The main problem is when I click the button it pops me back to the default route and says localhost:3000 could not load image, therefor not allowing me to even reach the route.

Answer (score 1):

You are not handling the events in meteor way. It should be in the following manner:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-insert">Insert</button>
```

Template events:

```
Template.template_name.events({
  "click .btn-insert": function() {
    //Your logic to submit form goes here...
    //on validating the form data and posting it successfully, navigate to the new route...
    FlowRouter.go('/joinLobby');
  }
});
```